# "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist" Django V2.0

Tags: django, python-3.x

I've recently upgraded Django to V2.0 and I'm unable to make migrations due to the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist
```

I know a similar bug existed in V1.8 which I fixed by migrating the model which others depend on, i.e. auth_user and then the rest:

```
python manage.py migrate auth
python manage.py migrate
```

When I try to migrate 'auth' I encounter the same error. Has anybody encountered/found a solution to this?

Comment: Is that a new application or you are updating Django in a pre-existing project?

Comment: New application, for various reasons I'd rather not downgrade

Comment: I am using Django 2.0 for about 6 weeks and I didn't get this problem. I am using Postgres and sqlite3 in different projects. My env is python 3.6.2 if it helps

Comment: That's what I'm using as well. However this error only occurs when I try to use PostGres

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered the same error.
At last I found the root cause was the database.
There may be some auth info in the database already.
Editing setting.py and using another new database will solve this problem.

Answer (score 5):

I have same issue even after creating new database.
What helped me, is choosing another owner, when creating new DB, not postgress owner. Also I was using

```
py manage.py migrate myapp
```

with this command, I have the same issue as well
But when I tried use

```
py manage.py migrate
```

and change owner from postgress on DB creating, it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem after I upgraded my DB with new/removed apps and forgot to upgrade my `asgi.py` and `wsgi.py` files to point to the upgraded `settingsprod.py` (for anyone who was following along with the eCommerce CodingWithStein). I then had to restart my nginx and gunicorn services.